# ターミナルコマンドの実行結果から任意のファイル名のファイルを書き出すアプリをXcodeで作成出来るでしょうか

Tags: xcode, macos

非常に初歩的な質問で大変恐縮です。

やりたいことは、

1. ユーザー自身にアプリをダウンロードしてもらい、ダブルクリック実行してもらう。
2. バックグラウンドにて任意のターミナルコマンド（sw_vers）を実行し実行結果からProductVersionの値をファイル名として任意のパスにファイルを作成。
3. ユーザーに完了のポップアップ表示。

ということをさせたいと考えています。

このような動作をさせるアプリケーションをXcodeで作成することは可能でしょうか。

また、任意のMac利用者へ配布して実行してもらうことを想定していますが、
開発環境以外のMac環境上で実行する場合、気を付けるべきことは有りますでしょうか。

内容が類似しているアプリのサンプルコードなどをご存じでしたらご教示頂けませんでしょうか。

宜しくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0):

> このような動作をさせるアプリケーションをXcodeで作成することは可能でしょうか。

可能ですよ